# MS UI Automation WinForms: Can't find grid field chooser window on UIA automation tree

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

We have an Infragistics UltraGrid control, and you can show a field chooser window for that grid.

[image: Field chooser shown]

However, the field chooser doesn't show up on the UIA automation tree.  If I try searching for it programmatically then UIA doesn't find it, same if I try to manually look for it using UIA Verify.

[image: Automation tree doesnt show field chooser]

But if I use UIA Verify hover/focus mode to find the field chooser, then it shows it, and also shows it under the same form as the grid control.

[image]

How do I find the control using code?  Why doesn't it show up on the automation tree?

Comment: Does it have AutomationID prop? How deep is it nested? Does it have same controlname, controlid, or name as other controls?

Comment: Yes, if I find it via hover/focus mode, it appears "normal".  It has ControlType.Window, AutomationId = "ColumnChooserDialog", Name = "Orders - Field chooser".  But if I search for those properties it doesn't find it... it I do a FindAll of the parent form and look through the children it doesn't show.

Comment: That sounds like a container window. The actual control is probably under that window.  ParentForm --> container window --> control

Comment: I added some images... the first one is how it appears normally in UIA Verify and through the code - the field chooser just doesn't show on the automation tree.  The second one shows that it does appear on the tree after I have found it using hover/focus mode in UIA Verify.

Comment: Bear in mind the UIA tree is a living thing. It probably means you need to trigger a user (inter)action (mouse, keyboard, click, hover, etc.) on the parent form so the field chooser window can be created (or be parented to it by infragistics code that would react to this action, if it already exist somewhere else). Difficult to help more w/o a simple repro code

Comment: I've added a picture at the start just to show that the field chooser window is shown.  I suppose I was wondering if it is a generic problem with UIA and if there is a solution?  i.e. the repro steps are to create an Infragistics grid and show the field chooser, and then inspect it using UIA Verify.

Comment: If you have VS ultimate, I would try using the CodedUI test builder spy to locate the control and then click the up arrow once you have located the control to scroll through the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the .NET framework related to forms created from MDI child forms.  As a workaround, I've been able to use the AutomationElement.FromPoint() function.

[Microsoft forum link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c699008a-686e-486f-abcf-6d122eeb59ff/inspect-objects-tool-does-not-show-forms-that-have-owner-property-set-in-the-tree-view?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation)

Quoting from Guy Barker (Microsoft):

"I can reproduce the issue you’re seeing. I set the main to be a mdi container, and created a child form, whose MdiParent is the main form. I then added the original owned form as owned by the mdi child form. When I did this, I could get the details of the owned form in Inspect, but the form didn’t appear in the UIA tree view.

Interestingly, when I view the ancestors of the owned form, it lists the mdi child form as the parent as expected. But for some reason, the mdi child form doesn’t consider the owned form to be one of its children.

I don’t have any suggestions as to how to workaround this at the moment, but I’ll post a comment here if I do find something."

Answer (score 0):

It's Infragistic. Some components like ultratree, ultragrid, etc are not located in correct order on object tree.

***Possible solutions:***

- Try to find your control from the **root** of the application window.
- Simulate mouse and keyboard actions.
- Get control as **AutomationElement.FocusedElement** and then go through elements parents